# How to update textview from fcm notification using data binding

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-databinding

Anyone please tell how to update the textview in an activity when an fcm notification arrives. The textview is update with the message in notification using data binding. How can we do this without using broadcast receiver

Comment: You are receiving notification in service, learn how to communicate with service, BroadcastReceiver is not the only way

Comment: tanq for your answer

Answer (score 0):

use custom broadcast receiver on MyFirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived method when notification arrives and update textview by fetching broadcast at desired location.